# Real Time Chat using Django channels in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, django-channels

I want to implement real-time chat features in the mobile app, I need to create RESTFUL APIs for this purpose.

Chat modes are as follows:

1. One-to-one: Between Individual Users, can include images in chat
2. One-to-Many: In a Group of Users, can include images in chat

There is no admin flow right now, How can I achieve this? any helping resource, please?

I also want to store chat and chat history, what should be my DB structure any expert opinion? I am using Postgres database.

Further, how is it possible to use Firebase? As the mobile app will be communicating with the REST APIs and REST API will be communicating to firebase, I think we can not achieve REAL-TIME COMMUNICATION in this case. AM I CORRECT?

Comment: check : https://fcm-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/; then design like user push chat the REST API, api will send it to Fire Base Cloud, and it send to the receiver.